# Category slug not showing on sitemap xml using Yoast plugin

Tags: xml, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I have this problem in my `sitemap.xml`. I was wondering why in the list, the category slug is not present while in the dashboard permalink section, the URL is displaying its category link.

Here are some of the screenshots to further explain what I mean:

- So in the image below you can see the links of the products and the links don't have its category being set in the dashboard:
  [image]
- Here is the screenshot showing what the links look like in the dashboard and what I expect the sitemap links to display:
  [image]

**Note:** This sitemap is generated via Yoast SEO plugin version 4.8.

Comment: Have you flushed/cleared the sitemap [cache](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/sitemap-does-not-update/)?

Comment: @SallyCJ any steps to do that? I have been touring around the dashboard looking for some cta to regenerate or cleared sitemap.xml for yoast but I couldn't find one. Please advice

Comment: Actually, I didn't really notice you're using Yoast SEO version 4.8? So try editing any of your "products" - e.g. on the "All Products" page in the back-end, click "Quick Edit" and then the "Update" button without actually making any changes, or *temporarily* change the slug (and later change it back) - and purge the W3 Total Cache cache.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, I tried doing what you've just suggested but no luck solving the issue. The sitemap url is still displaying links without the category slug.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't find a link to download the Yoast SEO plugin version 4.8; so can I have a copy of the plugin on your site so that I could test the plugin? And what version of WordPress and W3 Total Cache you're using?

Comment: Post your code for your custom post type, the issue will be related to that or it'll be your configuration of Yoast archive/posts.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to disable Cache plugins, or any plugins that might be related

2) Update related plugins (if they need) and also, you'd better update WordPress too (as seen in your screenshot, it needs update)

3) Regenerate Sitemap (update that page)

4) Check if fixed.

5) if so, then re-enable the above disabled plugins and then regenerate sitemap and see if it's broken again, then some plugin conflicts with it.